# PHP: cast to (array) and return-type: array is not the same?

Tags: php, variables, types, casting, return-type

I have following problem in PHP:

`print_r()` says it's the same, `gettype()` says same type, but the last output works not for both cases although they should be the same!

This looks very strange to me.

code and output:

```
$docdatau = get_object_vars(json_decode($docdata));
$docdatau2 = (array)json_decode($docdata);

echo "1\n";
echo gettype($docdatau);
echo "\n";
echo "--------------------------------------\n";
print_r($docdatau);
echo "--------------------------------------\n";

echo "2\n";
echo gettype($docdatau2);
echo "\n";
echo "--------------------------------------\n";
print_r($docdatau2);

echo "out1\n";
echo "--------------------------------------\n";
print_r($docdatau[0]);
echo "out2\n";
echo "--------------------------------------\n";
print_r($docdatau2[0]);
```

The output:

```
1
array
--------------------------------------
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [produkt] => Produkt 2
            [laufzeit] => 24
            [addtext] => sdsd
            [provision] => 39
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [produkt] => Produkt 1
            [laufzeit] => 
            [addtext] => 
            [provision] => 0
        )

)
--------------------------------------
2
array
--------------------------------------

Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [produkt] => Produkt 2
            [laufzeit] => 24
            [addtext] => sdsd
            [provision] => 39
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [produkt] => Produkt 1
            [laufzeit] => 
            [addtext] => 
            [provision] => 0
        )

)
out1
--------------------------------------
stdClass Object
(
    [produkt] => Produkt 2
    [laufzeit] => 24
    [addtext] => sdsd
    [provision] => 39
)
out2
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
```

`out1` and `out2` should produce the same results but don't.

Perhaps anybody has a hint for me?

Comment: The code you posted cannot correspond to the given output.  The output terminates with two "------" lines, but the code only prints one after "out2".  When you post code samples for bizarre problems like this, please **do not** edit them and take care to reproduce the **exact** code that gives you the output shown.

Comment: Is error reporting on? No output at all for `print_r` should usually be accompanied by an error.

Comment: @borealid: ok next time i'll do so. 
the code is unedited except the last line of dashes..

@deceze; Error reporting says <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 0 on line xy --> line is: (print_r($docdatau2[0]);)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several PHP bugs about it:

- http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45346
- http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51635
- http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46758

The same things happens here:

```
$obj->{0} = "hello";
$arr = (array)$obj;
echo $arr[0];
```

It happens because the "0" is used as string array key, whereas $arr[0] searches for the integer array key. It is documented in the PHP documentation simply by stating: *integer properties are unaccessible* ([link](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)).

Comment: that should be the answer. thank you.

i think php is an ugly language. you can't expect such a behaviour. and instead of fixing it, it becomes a "known issue that isn't a bug". i hope such things don't appear too often in PHP.

Comment: Don't count on it. This is fairly typical behavior.

Comment: what behaviour exactly do you mean? that bugs are declared as known issues? or that the same content of 2 variables can't be used the same way depending on where they came from?

so how to find out if an array is a "real" array or a casted object? gettype and print_r are both the same in both cases. wheres the difference?

an integer key is not accessible.. hm.. does it exist in an other way that an accessible integer key exists? 
who can't access that key? print_r could read the key and the cast operator could write the key. so it exists for me.
 
i think this is clearly a bug..

Comment: That bugs are declared as known issues. You can access the key using a foreach loop.

Comment: ok so how can i find out if an array is a "real" array or a casted object?