# PHP - Fill pulldown with array results from web service method

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

I currently have a web service (C#) that returns an array of strings to my client in PHP.

I want to fill a pulldown with the string elements in the array results.

With the following code, no items appear in the pulldown.

```
<select name="name-list" id="name-list" class="pulldown" onchange="exportName();" >
```

```
        $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/MyService.asmx?wsdl", array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
        $res = $client->GetServiceArray()->GetServiceArrayResult;

        $array  = (array)$res->ArrayOfString;
        foreach($array as $val)
        {
          echo "<option value=\"" . $val . "\">" . $val . "</option>\n";
        }

    ?>
```

I have also done var_dump($res) to make sure the web service is returning the data.  I can confirm that the values show in the page source.

It seems to be doing nothing on this line:

```
$array  = (array)$res->ArrayOfString;
```

Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Please can I have some advice on how to make the items appear.

Thank you.

Comment: you echo $array? do you mean $val? did you get errors? you should debug the code to verify that you get the right values through soap

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
foreach($array as $val)
{
    echo "<option value='$val'>$val</option>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but it still doesn't populate the pulldown

Comment: Have you reviewed the HTML source code? There might be valueable hints hidden in it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to do this

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $val . "\">" . $val . "</option>\n";
```

And don't forget to escape $val, because if there are any quotation characters inside, they will break your HTML. You can use

```
$val = addslashes($val);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but it still doesn't populate the pulldown.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be `$client->GetServiceArray()->GetServiceArrayResult` is actually a function? 
It should be `$client->GetServiceArray()->GetServiceArrayResult()` then.
In any way you should first check, if $res does contain any data: `var_dump($res);`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I tried this and it does return the contents of the array when I do var_dump($res).

Comment: But as you say, there are *no* pulldown items, your $array seems to be empty. Otherwise you'd receive empty pulldown items, which is a difference indeed.

Comment: `(array)$someObject` might end in unexpected result: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527872/php-cast-to-array-and-return-type-array-is-not-the-same